# Don't show if it is empty, how to do with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to Javascript and jQuery. I managed to make a dialog box with jQuery, it is giving a warning before submitting.

The problem is I don't want to show the label and field on the warning page if it is empty. I can't do this with PHP because form is not submitted. I need to do with jQuery or Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox-compressed.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // jQuery UI Dialog    
                 $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit Form": function() {
                            document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
                        },
                        "Cancel": function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('form#testconfirmJQ').submit(function(){
                    $("p#dialog-email").html($("input#emailJQ").val());
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="testconfirmJQ" name="testconfirmJQ" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input id="emailJQ" type="text" name="emailJQ" value="" />
<input id="submitJQ" name="submitJQ" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="dialog">
<p>E-mail</p>
<p id="dialog-email"></p>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is Validation.

To not reinvent the wheel, have a look [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

**Edit**

```
var email = $("input#emailJQ").val();
if (email === "") {
    $('#dialog-email').addClass('hidden');
}
```

and then you can define a hidden class in your stylesheet

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

To hide even the "E-mail" paragraph label then you need to assign an id to the `<p>` tag or better wrap the two in a block element with an ID and assign the class to that element

Comment: the problem is i do not want to validate, i just don`t want to show it if it is empty.

Comment: have a look at my edit if it answer your question even if  I am not sure to completely understand your requirement

Comment: ok. i think i couldn`t explain properly. If email field is empty i don`t want to show  <p>E-mail</p> 
<p id="dialog-email"></p> 
 but i still want to show <div id="dialog"></div Because i have got other stuff to add to the form

Comment: Me too.. Hope that I did understand now :)

Comment: i will try that... this does not work. Any idea why? $('form#testconfirmJQ').submit(function(){
                    $("p#dialog-email").html($("input#emailJQ").val());
     
     if($.trim($("input#emailJQ").val()).length==0)
                    $("p#email").hide();
     
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

Comment: stupid me.. it is working now. i did under <div> instead of <p>

Comment: Ok! great that you've found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

ok... I am done, it is working now.

Thank you Lorenzo

-edited again-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox-compressed.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // jQuery UI Dialog    
                 $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit Form": function() {
                            document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
                        },
                        "Cancel": function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('form#testconfirmJQ').submit(function(){
                    $("p#dialog-email").html($("input#emailJQ").val());

                    if($.trim($("p#dialog-email").val()).length==0)
        {
            $("p#email").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("p#email").show();
        }       

                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

                    return false;
                });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="testconfirmJQ" name="testconfirmJQ" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input id="emailJQ" type="text" name="emailJQ" value="" />
<input id="submitJQ" name="submitJQ" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="dialog">
<p id="email">E-mail</p>
<p id="dialog-email"></p>
</div>


</body>
```